# Atlaskit datePicker hidden by the container div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atlaskit

I am using atlaskit date picker and DateTime picker. I am facing issue with position datePicker hidden by the container div.
atlaskit/datetime-picker - version 10.0.1
Reactjs - 16.13.0

```
<DatePicker
  label={label}
  isRequired={Data1.required}
  onChange={(e) => this.onChangeField(e, key, type, 'Date')}
  defaultValue={defValue}
  isDisabled={!this.props.isEditIssuePermission}
  dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
  placeholder="Select Date"
/>
```

[image]